# How to reverse colors order for the first label?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a horizontal stacked bars with 3 labels with the same order for the colors. I would like to know how can I reverse the color order for the first label only so that it goes from **dark blue to dark red** and keep the same color flow for label 2 and 3.

https://jsfiddle.net/samwhite/s9yzuqd5/

[image]

```
var colors = ['#93003a', '#f4777f', '#ffb040', '#a5d5d8', '#00429d'];
var def_color = '#d3d3d3';

    let labels = [
      "In my organization, more emphasis is placed on quantity of work than on the quality of work",
      "My Division/Office/Region is making real, meaningful progress on diversity, inclusion, and opportunity in our workplace",
      "In my Division/Office/Region, I am given a fair opportunity to work on visible, career-enhancing assignments"
    ];

    // Construct the chart
    let chart = Highcharts.chart('container1_1', {
      ...
      yAxis: {
        title: { text: 'Response Rate' },
        max: 100,
        maxPadding: 0,
        labels: {
          format: '{value}%'
        },
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        minorGridLineWidth: 0
      },
      ...
      xAxis: {
        categories: labels,
        labels: {
          style: {
            fontSize: '1em',
            color: '#000',
            width: 370,
            float: 'left'
          }
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Strongly Agree',
        color: colors[4],
        data: []
      }, {
        name: 'Agree',
        color: colors[3],
        data: []
      }, {
        name: 'Neither Agree nor Disagree',
        color: colors[2],
        data: []
      }, {
        name: 'Disagree',
        color: colors[1],
        data: []
      }, {
        name: 'Strongly Disagree',
        color: colors[0],
        data: []
      }]
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added Color on each data set to work in the color scheme needed based on the index

you can see the reference here: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.data

```
 {
                                            name: tooltip_titles[s],
                                            color: colors[Math.abs(s - 4)],
                                                        y: dept_data["102"][4-s]
                                            },
```

Old - https://jsfiddle.net/jouwsLn0/

New - https://jsfiddle.net/js1bfxe5/1/

```
 series: [{
        name: 'Strongly Agree',
        color: colors[4],
        data: []
      }, {
        name: 'Agree',
        color: colors[3],
        data: []
      }, {
        name: 'Neither Agree nor Disagree',
        color: colors[2],
        data: []
      }, {
        name: 'Disagree',
        color: colors[1],
        data: []
      }, {
        name: 'Strongly Disagree',
        color:   colors[0],
        data: []
      }]
    });

    $("#filterOrganization").change(function () {
      $(this).find("option:selected")
        .each(function () {
          var optionValue = $(this).text();
          let dept_data = data[optionValue];
          chart.series.forEach((series, s) => {
          console.log(s);
          console.log(dept_data["102"][4-s]);
            series.setData([
            
                                        {
                                            name: tooltip_titles[s],
                                            color: colors[Math.abs(s - 4)],
                                                        y: dept_data["102"][4-s]
                                            },
                          {
                                            name: tooltip_titles[s],
                                            color: colors[s],
                                                        y: dept_data["104"][4-s]
                                            },
                          {
                                            name: tooltip_titles[s],
                                            color: colors[s],
                                                        y: dept_data["105"][4-s]
                                            }]);
          });
        });
    }).change();
```

Comment: Hi Prikesh, thanks for the response. This does not work properly unfortunately. The legends at the bottom are already getting grayed out with this approach.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/js1bfxe5/1/ How does this look then?

Comment: That looks good! I will go ahead and accept your answer now. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hey, I updated the answer so its easier for you to follow the change

Comment: Great! Really appreciate all the help.

Comment: can you help with one more thing. It looks like the tooltip is not functioning properly. when you hover over any of the colors in the first bar, it's highlighting the rest two bars as well and the tooltip is only showing up for the first label.

Comment: Can you please help fix that as well?